# Обобщенный конвертер EAP => TAP

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, async-await, task

У меня есть объект - клиент, который подключается к серверу посредством сокет соединения. Это означает, что, когда мне что то надо получить с сервера, я отправляю ему пакет запроса, а он, когда ему понравится, мне ответит. Соответственно, вся логика ответов завязана на эвентах - то есть в момент, когда я получаю ответ, я понятия не имею, какой из запросов этот ответ мне предоставил.

У меня возникла мысль, что это не очень хорошо, и гораздо структурированней было бы перевести эту модель на модель запросов-ответов. 
Для эксперимента я подготовил базовый класс

```
public class Foo
{
    public event EventHandler<FooEArgs> SomeEvent;
    public void SomeEventInvocator()
    {           
        SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, new FooEArgs());
    }

    public Action<Foo> SomeDelegate;
    public void SomeDelegateInvocator()
    {
        SomeDelegate?.Invoke(this);
    }

    public Task SendEvent()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); SomeEventInvocator(); });
    }

    public Task SendDelegate()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); SomeDelegateInvocator(); });
    }

    public class FooEArgs : EventArgs
    {
    }
}
```

Да, эвенты могут быть в виде эвентов, а могут быть просто делегатами. Не спрашивайте - это унаследованный код 3-party библиотеки. Мне просто приходится с этим жить.

Далее, я написал методы для ожидания события и делегата

```
public Task WaitForDelegate(Foo foo)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    Action<Foo> handler = null;
    handler = (s) =>
    {
        foo.SomeDelegate -= handler;
        tcs.SetResult(0);
    };

    foo.SomeDelegate += handler;

    return tcs.Task;
}

public Task WaitForEvent(Foo foo)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    EventHandler<Foo.FooEArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) => {
        foo.SomeEvent-=handler;
        tcs.SetResult(0);
    };

    foo.SomeEvent +=handler;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Они вроде работают, но они строго типизированные. Тогда я попробовал написать Generic метод хотя бы для события

```
private async Task WaitForEvent<T>(Action<EventHandler<T>> addEvent, 
    Action<EventHandler<T>> removeEvent, 
    TimeSpan timeout, 
    EventHandler<T> customHandler = null)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    EventHandler<T> handler = null;

    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        removeEvent(handler);
        customHandler?.Invoke(s, e);
        tcs.SetResult(0);
    };

    addEvent(handler);

    await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(timeout));
}
```

Тестирование методов:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.SendEvent();    
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for event.");
    await WaitForEvent(foo);
    Console.WriteLine("Event raised.");

    foo.SendDelegate();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for delegate.");
    await WaitForDelegate(foo);
    Console.WriteLine("Delegate raised.");

    foo.SendEvent();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for event.");
    await WaitForEvent<Foo.FooEArgs>(h => foo.SomeEvent += h, h => foo.SomeEvent -= h, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), (s, e) => {Console.WriteLine("Inside event!");});
    Console.WriteLine("Event raised."); 
}
```

Вывод результата:

```
Waiting for event.
Event raised.
Waiting for delegate.
Delegate raised.
Waiting for event.
Inside event!
Event raised.
```

Этот метод отрабатывает, но остается вопрос - такое вообще приемлемо? Можно ли этот код переписать на более стабильный/понятный? Также минусы у кода тоже есть, например, по хорошему запрос на сервер должен уходить уже после подписки, а не перед подпиской на событие.

Конечно я читал [How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-wrap-eap-patterns-in-a-task), однако, мой случай отличается тем, что у меня возможна ситуация, когда много потоков одновременно отправляют серверу одинаковые и/или разные запросы, и потом с сервера может приехать пачка одинаковых и/или разных событий - собственно, я надеюсь, что в новой имплементации я смогу также кешировать таски, чтобы разгрузить сервер от подобных вещей. Также события могут приходить сами по себе, без каких либо запросов от клиента.

Таким образом, мне нужно ревью моего кода, и, возможно, сообщество поможет мне его улучшить или наоборот отказаться от этой идеи.

**UPD**

А итоге родился вот такой класс

```
public static class EventAwaiter
{
    public static IEventAwaiter<T> FromEvent<T>(Action<EventHandler<T>> addEvent, Action<EventHandler<T>> removeEvent)
    {
        return new EventAwaiterInternal<T>(addEvent, removeEvent);
    }

    public static IEventAwaiter<T> WithTimeout<T>(this IEventAwaiter<T> target, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        return target.SetTimeout(timeout);
    }

    public static IEventAwaiter<T> WithHandler<T>(this IEventAwaiter<T> target, EventHandler<T> handler)
    {
        return target.SetCustomHandler(handler);
    }   

    public interface IEventAwaiter<T>
    {
        IEventAwaiter<T> SetTimeout(TimeSpan tieout);
        IEventAwaiter<T> SetCustomHandler(EventHandler<T> handler);
        Task Wait(Action raiseEvent = null, Func<object, T, bool> matchEvent = null);
    }   

    private class EventAwaiterInternal<T> : IEventAwaiter<T>
    {
        private readonly Action<EventHandler<T>> _addEvent;
        private readonly Action<EventHandler<T>> _removeEvent;
        private TimeSpan _timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        private EventHandler<T> _customHandler;

        public EventAwaiterInternal(Action<EventHandler<T>> addEvent, Action<EventHandler<T>> removeEvent)
        {
            _addEvent = addEvent;
            _removeEvent = removeEvent;
        }

        public IEventAwaiter<T> SetTimeout(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            _timeout = timeout;
            return this;
        }

        public IEventAwaiter<T> SetCustomHandler(EventHandler<T> handler)
        {
            _customHandler = handler;
            return this;
        }

        public async Task Wait(Action raiseEvent = null, Func<object, T, bool> matchEvent = null)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            EventHandler<T> handler = null;

            handler = (s, e) =>
            {
                if (matchEvent != null && !matchEvent(s, e)) return;

                _removeEvent(handler);
                _customHandler?.Invoke(s, e);
                tcs.SetResult(0);
            };

            _addEvent(handler);

            raiseEvent?.Invoke();

            await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.Delay(_timeout));
            _removeEvent(handler);
        }
    }   
}
```

Вызов его выглядит вот так

```
var foo = new Foo();

await EventAwaiter.FromEvent<Foo.FooEArgs>(h=>foo.SomeEvent+=h, h=>foo.SomeEvent-=h)
.WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
.WithHandler((s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Inside!"))
.Wait(()=>foo.SendEvent());
```

По мне так запись довольно короткая получилась.