# Как дождаться закрытия формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу автономное приложение, я вызываю форму

```
Form f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();

while(true)
{
if (//Форма закрта)
break;
}
//дальнейший код
```

в ней срабатывает таймер, который запускает последовательность действий, после чего происходит `this.Close();`

Как я могу проверить, что форма закрылась из основной(родительской)?

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, Вам нужно подписаться на событие FormClosed той формы, закрытие которой надо отловить.

Comment: Примерно в этом смысле, я вхожу в `while()` и жду пока форма отработает и закроется

Comment: Программирование WindowsForms - это [событийно-ориентированное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Событийно-ориентированное_программирование) программирование. За ожидание события в цикле `while` следует давать семь лет расстрела без права доступа к компьютеру. Как вам уже сказали, подписывайтесь на нужное _событие_ и по его получении выполняйте необходимые действия. ЗЫ: чисто к сведению: в любом приложении с GUI уже реализован цикл - это цикл обработки сообщений `WndProc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (.NET 4.5+):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

...

//Вспомогательный метод: Создает объект Task, который может использоваться для ожидания срабатывания указанного события 
public static Task<object> GetTaskFromEvent(object o, string evt)
{
    if (o == null || evt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Arguments cannot be null");

    EventInfo einfo = o.GetType().GetEvent(evt);
    if (einfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("*{0}* has no *{1}* event", o, evt));
    }

    TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    MethodInfo mi = null;
    Delegate deleg = null;
    EventHandler handler = null;

    //код обработчика события
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        mi = handler.Method;
        deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(einfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, mi);
        einfo.RemoveEventHandler(s, deleg); //отцепляем обработчик события
        tcs.TrySetResult(null); //сигнализируем о наступлении события
    };

    mi = handler.Method;
    deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(einfo.EventHandlerType, handler.Target, mi); //получаем делегат нужного типа
    einfo.AddEventHandler(o, deleg); //присоединяем обработчик события
    return tcs.Task;
}


private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f = new Form1();
    f.Show();

    await GetTaskFromEvent(f, "FormClosed");
    //дальнейший код...

}
```

Comment: Почему бы не просто `f.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: @tym32167 Так вопрос вроде "Как дождаться закрытия формы", а не "Как показать модальное диалоговое окно"

Comment: Мое показалось, что именно это надо автору. Но даже если это не так, ваше решение выглядит немного сложно, как считаете?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну просто уже была заготовка метода для ожидания произвольного события, я ее и перенес сюда. Если нужно ждать одно заданное событие, конечно извращения с reflection не нужны.

Comment: Я как то делал что то [подобное для себя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828845/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-eap-tap), и хотя там есть ограничения по типам событий (должен быть `EventHandler<T>`) - поглядите, может будет вам интересно

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а в чем смысл заморачиваться с преобразованием события в Task? Почему бы просто не подписаться 1 строчкой?

Comment: @iluxa1810 А как одной строчкой? Task нужен, чтобы можно было сделать await и ждать события без блокирования основного потока. Есть конечно способ сделать это без await, но точно не одной строчкой.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хотя да... не так все просто.