# Задача на многопоточность. Полусинхронный вызов делегата

Tags: c#, делегаты

Задача
В .net есть возможность звать делегаты как синхронно:

```
EventHandler h = new EventHandler(this.myEventHandler); 
h.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty); 
так и асинхронно:
var res = h.BeginInvoke(null, EventArgs.Empty, null, null);
```

Нужно реализовать возможность полусинхронного вызова делегата (написать реализацию класса AsyncCaller), который бы работал таким образом:

```
EventHandler h = new EventHandler(this.myEventHandler); 
ac = new AsyncCaller(h); 
bool completedOK = ac.Invoke(5000, null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Полусинхронного в данном случае означает, что делегат будет вызван, и вызывающий поток будет ждать, пока вызов не выполнится.  Но если выполнение делегата займет больше 5000 миллисекунд, то ac.Invoke выйдет и вернет в completedOK значение false.

Подскажите как лучше делать, или что посмотреть.

Comment: Как вы в асинхронность варианте поймете, что делегаты еще не выполнился или уже выполнился? Коллбеки будете использовать? Если вам надо ожидать чего то, почему бы не ожидать асинхроннно?

Comment: Я когда то баловался [вот таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828845/179763), может вас на какие мысли натолкнет.

Comment: Такое вот задание, я думаю может в торону класса Action посмотеть и в нем метод invoke переопределить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы просите странного, `Delegate.BeginInvoke` [не поддерживается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194245/12888024) со времен .NET Core 2.0, то есть достаточно давно. EAP устарел, позвольте ему покоиться с миром. Пора бы уже изучать [TAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).

Но если очень хочется, то почему бы и нет.

```cs
class Program
{
    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Handler");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Exit Handler");
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        EventHandler h = new EventHandler(MyEventHandler);
        AsyncCaller ac = new AsyncCaller(h);
        if (ac.Invoke(5000, this, EventArgs.Empty))
            Console.WriteLine("Completed successfully");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Timeout occured");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class AsyncCaller
{
    private readonly EventHandler handler;
    private Thread thread;

    public AsyncCaller(EventHandler handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    private void Aborter(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        thread?.Abort();
    }

    private void Wait(object timeout)
    {
        Thread.Sleep((int)timeout);
    }

    public bool Invoke(int timeout, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread = new Thread(Wait);
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = handler?.BeginInvoke(sender, e, Aborter, this);
        thread.Start(timeout);
        thread.Join();
        thread = null;
        return asyncResult.IsCompleted;
    }
}
```

Запускаем делегат, который работает секунду, получаем:

```cs
Enter Handler
Exit Handler
Completed successfully
Done.
```

Меняем 1000 на 6000, получаем

```
Enter Handler
Timeout occured
Done.
Exit Handler
```

А теперь то же самое, только с использованием TAP

```cs
private static async Task HandleAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Handler");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Exit Handler");
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = HandleAsync();
    if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(5000)) == t)
        Console.WriteLine("Completed successfully");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout occured");
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод при аналогичных ожиданиях такой же.

---

Обе реализации не идеальны и я бы допилил в сторону усложнения и более оптимальной работы с потоками, но оставил чем проще - тем лучше, главное чтобы работало.

Comment: я верно понял, в первом случае у вас ожидение всегда будет минимум 5 секунд, незваисимо от скорости асинхронного вызова?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, не верно поняли :)

Comment: а, точно, пропустил Aborter

Comment: `Thread.Abort`? o_O

Comment: @VladD ну можно SpinWait какой-нибудь крутить, но суть от этого не поменяется. В самом конце ответа легкий дислеймер, который это замечание в том числе в себя включает.

Comment: @aepot: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/thread-abort-obsolete

Comment: @VladD эммм. А `Delegate.BeginInvoke` никто не заметил? Который был выпилен вообще 100 лет назад )))

Comment: @aepot: Это правда, но `Thread.Abort` был ужасен всегда. Вот ещё пример: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/ericlippert/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix

Comment: @VladD да тут весь ответ ужасен как всё EAP полностью вместе взятое :)

Comment: @aepot: Или вот это попробуйте: https://pastebin.com/TgzNNqB5

Comment: @VladD ахахах) ну да, так оно работает (работало). На практике я никогда не юзал `Abort` и не планирую. Я вообще не юзаю `Thread`, потому что есть `Task` и `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Там недавно в .NET 6 добавили фичу `WaitAsync(TimeSpan)`, если хотите можете добавить/изменить ответ