C# Потокобезопасный Dictionary с асинхронным ожиданием изменений
Задача - создать потокобезопасный словарь, позволяющий асинхронно ожидать обновление значений по ключу. При том, если в значениях используется специальная коллекция, отслеживаются изменения внутри самой коллекции. Если значение было добавлено или обновлено до того, как пользователь вызывал метод ожидания обновлений, возврат происходит незамедлительно. Каким образом можно оптимизировать данный словарь для работы в высоконагруженной среде? Буду рад любым предложениям по улучшению (в том числе и не касающихся улучшений производительности).
public enum CollectionChangedAction {
    ItemAdded, 
    ItemRemoved, 
    ItemUpdated,
    Reset
}

public class CollectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {

    public CollectionChangedAction Action { get; private set; }

    public CollectionChangedEventArgs(CollectionChangedAction action) => Action = action;
}

public interface IObservableCollection {
    public event EventHandler<CollectionChangedEventArgs> CollectionChanged;
}

public class AsyncDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> {

    private class DefaultEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> {
        public static DefaultEqualityComparer<T> Instance { get; } = new DefaultEqualityComparer<T>();
        private DefaultEqualityComparer() { }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y) {
            if (default(T) == null) return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj) {
            if (default(T) == null)
                return obj != null ? RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj) : 0;
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Управляет подпиской на события изменения коллекции.
    /// </summary>
    private class CollectionChangedHandlerController {

        private EventHandler<CollectionChangedEventArgs> EventHandler;

        /// <summary>
        /// Подключенная наблюдаемая коллекция.
        /// </summary>
        public IObservableCollection Collection { get; private set; }

        public CollectionChangedHandlerController(IObservableCollection collection) {
            Collection = collection;
        }

        public void AddHandler(EventHandler<CollectionChangedEventArgs> eventHandler) {
            if (eventHandler == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventHandler));
            if (EventHandler != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Обработчик уже зарегистрирован для данного события.");

            if (Collection != null) {
                EventHandler = eventHandler;
                Collection.CollectionChanged += eventHandler;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveHandler() {
            if (EventHandler != null) {
                Collection.CollectionChanged -= EventHandler;
                EventHandler = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly bool IsObservableCollectionInValue;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> InnerDictionary;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, CollectionChangedHandlerController> InnerCollectionsDictionary;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TaskCompletionSource> Awaiters = new();
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> ValueEqualityComparer = DefaultEqualityComparer<TValue>.Instance;

    public int Count => IsObservableCollectionInValue ? InnerCollectionsDictionary.Count : InnerDictionary.Count;

    public bool IsEmpty => IsObservableCollectionInValue ? InnerCollectionsDictionary.IsEmpty : InnerDictionary.IsEmpty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Типы отслеживаемых изменений коллекции.
    /// </summary>
    public CollectionChangedAction[] TrackedChangeActions { get; private set; }

    public AsyncDictionary() {
        IsObservableCollectionInValue = typeof(TValue).IsAssignableTo(typeof(IObservableCollection));
        if (!IsObservableCollectionInValue) InnerDictionary = new();
        else {
            InnerCollectionsDictionary = new();
            TrackedChangeActions = [
                CollectionChangedAction.ItemAdded,
                CollectionChangedAction.ItemRemoved,
                CollectionChangedAction.ItemUpdated,
                CollectionChangedAction.Reset];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса <see cref="AsyncDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/>, 
    /// задавая отслеживаемые типы изменений коллекции.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trackedChangeActions">
    /// Массив отслеживаемых типов изменений, происходящих в коллекции.
    /// </param>
    public AsyncDictionary(CollectionChangedAction[] trackedChangeActions) : this() {
        if (trackedChangeActions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(trackedChangeActions));
        if (!IsObservableCollectionInValue)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Отслеживание изменений поддерживается только для значений, реализующих интерфейс IObservableCollection.");

        TrackedChangeActions = trackedChangeActions.Distinct().ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса <see cref="AsyncDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/>, 
    /// копируя элементы из указанного словаря.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="valueEqualityComparer">
    /// Необязательный компаратор значений для определения необходимости уведомлений об обновлениях. 
    /// Если не указан, используется компаратор по умолчанию.
    /// </param>
    public AsyncDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueEqualityComparer = null) : this() {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));

        InnerDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
        foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys) {
            var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
            completionSource.SetResult();
            Awaiters.TryAdd(key, completionSource);
        }

        if (valueEqualityComparer != null)
            ValueEqualityComparer = valueEqualityComparer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавляет новый элемент или обновляет существующий элемент в словаре.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue value) {
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            void onCollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
                if (TrackedChangeActions.Contains(e.Action) &&
                    Awaiters.TryGetValue(key, out var completionSource) &&
                    !completionSource.Task.IsCompleted) {
                    completionSource.SetResult();
                }
            };

            var newValue = new CollectionChangedHandlerController((IObservableCollection)value);
            newValue.AddHandler(onCollectionChanged);
            InnerCollectionsDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, newValue, (key, existingValue) => {
                existingValue.RemoveHandler();
                return newValue;
            });
        } else {
            bool newValueProduced = true;
            InnerDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (key, existingValue) => {
                newValueProduced = !ValueEqualityComparer.Equals(value, existingValue);
                return value;
            });

            if (newValueProduced)
                Awaiters.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new TaskCompletionSource()).TrySetResult();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Пытается получить значение из словаря по ключу.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            if (InnerCollectionsDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var handlerController)) {
                value = (TValue)handlerController.Collection;
                return true;
            }
            value = default;
            return false;
        } else {
            return InnerDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Пытается удалить элемент из словаря по ключу.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TryRemove(TKey key) {
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            if (!InnerCollectionsDictionary.TryRemove(key, out var handlerController))
                return false;
            handlerController.RemoveHandler();
        } else if (!InnerDictionary.TryRemove(key, out _)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Awaiters.TryRemove(key, out var completionSource))
            completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Очищает словарь, удаляя все элементы.
    /// </summary>
    public void Clear() {
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            var handlerControllers = InnerCollectionsDictionary.Values.ToArray();
            InnerCollectionsDictionary.Clear();
            foreach (var handlerController in handlerControllers)
                handlerController.RemoveHandler();
        } else {
            InnerDictionary.Clear();
        }

        var completionSources = Awaiters.Values.ToArray();
        Awaiters.Clear();
        foreach (var completionSource in completionSources)
            completionSource.TrySetCanceled();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Асинхронно ожидает изменения значения для указанного ключа.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Ключ отслеживаемого значения.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Токен отмены операции.</param>
    /// <returns>Обновлённое значение, связанное с указанным ключом.</returns>
    public async ValueTask<TValue> WaitForUpdate(TKey key, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var completionSource = Awaiters.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new TaskCompletionSource());
        await completionSource.Task.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        Awaiters.TryUpdate(key, new TaskCompletionSource(), completionSource);

        TValue value;
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            if (!InnerCollectionsDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var handlerController))
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            value = (TValue)handlerController.Collection;
        } else {
            if (!InnerDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }

        return value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() {
        if (IsObservableCollectionInValue) {
            return InnerCollectionsDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                pair => (TValue)pair.Value.Collection).GetEnumerator();
        }

        return InnerDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}


Чет как то сложно получилось. Я бы тупо сделал словарь с событиями, а ожидание уже пусть клиент делает или отдельным методом. Можно же просто асинхронно ожидать событие, словарю вообще нет необходимости знать что его кто то ожидает.

При том, если в значениях используется специальная коллекция, отслеживаются изменения внутри самой коллекции. по идее это требование к словарю не относится. Словарю то какая разница что там в значениях.

Это коллекция для удобства решения специфичных задач. Требования именно такие. Может быть тогда предложите иное название для этой штуки?) Единственное, возможно, функциональность которая отвечает за отслеживание изменений в коллекциях-значениях можно вынести в отдельный класс, если так было бы более "правильно".

Да, я как раз про то, чтобы отделить мух от котлет. Ожидание события, словарь с событиями и коллекция в values - это три разные задачи, просто предлагаю их решить отдельно и комбинировать уже там, где вам надо в нужных вам комбинациях

Например, как ожидать события я писал тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828845/179763, ну или можете каким реактивным фреймворком воспользоваться если там есть что то подобное

"Например, как ожидать события я писал тут ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828845/179763" - Мне нравится идея, но здесь не совсем подходит. Дело в том, что нужно по сути не ожидать события, а считывать факт изменения объекта в значении по ключу. То есть например если значение было добавлено в словарь, первый вызов метода должен вернуться немедленно, а второй (последовательный) уже когда значение изменилось. Почему я вообще задал этот вопрос - есть сомнение в 100% безопасности работы с коллекцией Awaiters (лучше даже сказать всей логики, где есть взаимодействие с Awaiters).

И снова велосипеды. Есть же интерфейсы INotifyCollectionChanged и INotifyPropertyChanged. И готовые их реализации ObservableCollection<T>, BindingList<T>. Добавить контроль уникальности значений и готово без лишних плясок с велосипедами. Вам бы с .NET поближе познакомиться, там много всего готового. При чём реализации INPC и INCC поддерживаются нативно в интерфейсах WPF, Winforms и любых других. К тому же словарь должен реализовать IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, а у вас где это?

@aepot ObservableCollection не подходит (посмотрите мой предыдущий комментарий). А INotifyCollectionChanged подразумевает использование NotifyCollectionChangedAction, в котором несоответствующий набор значений (например события типа Move не нужны).

Ну не нужны, значит бросайте NotSupportedException или вообще ничего не делайте. Половина дотнета так устроена, попробуйте тот же Stream отнаследовать, там больше половины ненужного будет. Но тем не менее, наследуют, и всё работает.

Кстати, а вы знакомы с шаблоном проектирование Producer/Consumer? Если нет, то пора знакомиться. Второе - слышали что-нибудь про System.Threading.Channels? Я к тому что для решения задачи (то что оригинальная, а не ту что про словарь), вообще может оказаться что словарь не нужен. Здесь как минимум SOLID/SRP нарушен. Коллекция не должна отвечать за то что происходит внутри её элементов. Вам наверняка не за словарём надо следить а за потоком данных, его изменяющих, верно? Словарь то для чего - он кеш? Кеш чего? Откуда куда эти данные идут и для чего используются? Так много вопросов....

@aepot Да, вы правы, конечно оригинальная задача не про словарь. Но мне показалось что было бы удобно именно так её решить. Я приведу пример конкретной задачи (подобных задач накопилось множество, поэтому нужно универсальное решение): есть один поток, который слушает HTTP порт и получает уведомления от сервиса; есть множество других потоков, которые должны эти уведомления получать. НО, все уведомления сгруппированы по некоторым ID (как это происходит, когда например в соцсети мы получаем разные уведомления в разных чатах и у этих чатов есть ID), по которым их можно извлекать.

@aepot И важно, чтобы можно было асинхронно получать обновления. Обновления могут быть разными - появилось обновление объекта либо добавился новый объект(ы).

Ну вот, вы только что рассказали, что вам нужен банальный Channel<T>, а точнее столько каналов, сколько типов слушателей. А получатель данных будет просто выбирать нужный канал в зависимости от типа сообщения и слать в него то что пришло. Готово. Вообще 0 коллекций.

@aepot Тогда можно использовать ConcurrentDictionary<int, Channel<T>>, если я правильно понял. Извлекаем по int ID нужный канал и работаем с ним. Но ещё остаётся вопрос с 1 объектом, обновления состояния которого мы получаем. Может быть так же применять ConcurrentDictionary, но в качестве значения создать класс наследующий что то вроде IValueTaskSource? Просто было бы удобно сделать например поле Value с актуальной версией объекта + возможность await'ить этот объект, когда есть несчитанное изменение.

Здесь уж на что фантазии хватит. Главное, решается задача с ожиданием сообщения, которую будет решать канал, а не словарь. Кстати ConcurrentDictionary<int, Channel<T>> вы не сможете создать, поймёте когда попробуете, почему. Но сделать брокер каналов не сложно, который будет создавать каналы и барыжить читателями и писателями в эти каналы. Здесь скорее будет <int, object> или даже <Type, object>, но для внутренней логики брокера это не страшно.

@aepot А что можно сделать с ситуацией, когда нужно только посмотреть первый элемент в канале не извлекая его? Ещё было бы не плохо автоматически удалять каналы, которые давно не использовались.


можно взять из канала элемент и обратно его туда закинуть 2) если канал больше не нужен, его можно закрыть вручную


@aepot "1) можно взять из канала элемент и обратно его туда закинуть" - Можно вернуть в начало канала? "2) если канал больше не нужен, его можно закрыть вручную" - Я о том что скорее всего нужно создавать обёртку над Channel, позволяющую смотреть время записи, чтобы можно было понять, что канал давно не использовался.

У вас в канале что, огромная очередь будет? Как вы тогда словарь с одним элементом планировали использовать и вас всё устраивало? Вообще зачем класть в канал то, чего там не должно быть? А если вы кладёте только нужное, то тогда с "посмотреть" я не понимаю, что за манёвр. Но вообще ваши вопросы уже не связаны с изначальным. Советую задать новый вопрос отдельно.

Не должен словарь заниматься содержимым своих значений. Этим заниматься должен кто-то другой, например Channel<T>.
Допустим, пусть будет вот такое сообщение TextMessage
public interface IMessage { }

public class GenericMessage<T> : IMessage
{
    public T Body { get; init; } 
}

public class TextMessage : GenericMessage<string> { }

Тогда "на коленке" можно написать вот такой класс
public class MessageDispatcher
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _channels = new();

    public ChannelReader<T> GetConsumer<T>() where T : IMessage
    {
        if (_channels.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Consumer for {typeof(T).Name} is already registered");
        var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<T>();
        _channels.TryAdd(typeof(T), channel.Writer);
        // если канал закрывается, следующая строчка удалит его из словаря автоматически
        channel.Reader.Completion.ContinueWith(_ => _channels.Remove(typeof(T), out object _));
        return channel.Reader;
    }

    public ChannelWriter<T> GetProducer<T>() where T: IMessage
    {
        return _channels.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out object instance)
            ? (ChannelWriter<T>)instance
            : throw new InvalidOperationException($"Consumer for {typeof(T).Name} is not registered");
    }
}

Конечно, я не уверен, что его логика вам на 100% подойдёт, но как пример должно быть норм.
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageDispatcher dispatcher = new();
        var reader = dispatcher.GetConsumer<TextMessage>();
        Task consumerTask = ConsumeTextMessageAsync(reader);

        var writer = dispatcher.GetProducer<TextMessage>();
        writer.TryWrite(new TextMessage { Body = "Hello" });
        writer.TryWrite(new TextMessage { Body = "World" });
        writer.Complete();

        await consumerTask;
        try
        {
            writer = dispatcher.GetProducer<TextMessage>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static async Task ConsumeTextMessageAsync(ChannelReader<TextMessage> reader)
    {
        await foreach (TextMessage message in reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {message.Body}");
        }
    }
}

Запускаю
Message received: Hello
Message received: World
Consumer for TextMessage is not registered

Вроде работает, и обработка ошибок тоже работает.
То есть можно напилить и отнаследовать каких угодно типов сообщений, и для каждого типа будет свой канал, который по типу того же сообщения и можно создать.
Конечно в коде выше реализована схема "один консьюмер = сколько угодно продюсеров", но по сути канал технически позволяет сделать как сколько угодно консьюмеров, так и сколько угодно продюсеров, например для балансоровки нагрузки между консьюмерами. Канал - штука мощная и имеет очень серьёзную производительность.

Было бы удобно если бы GetConsumer возвращал ChannelReader даже если ключ уже существует. Почему всё таки Channel нельзя прямо добавлять в словарь? Я попробовал элементарный сценарий с добавлением канала и значения в одном потоке и чтением из другого.

@D.Stark, Почему всё таки Channel нельзя прямо добавлять в словарь? - можно. просто с каким-то конкретным <T> и этот <T> должен быть "одинаковым" для всех элементов словаря. В комментарии, говорилось про Channel<T> и не было понятно откуда этот <T>  берется

@D.Stark почему нельзя? Можно. Я всего-лишь пример показал. Можете и существующий возвращать, если надо.

Под T подразумевался какой то конкретный тип
